# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program in Dynatrace

Tags: .net, clr, .net-2.0, dynatrace

I can see that there was a lot of issues with this error message everywhere on the net. But I use Framework 2.0 with Visual Studio 2005. We have a set of web applications that calls web services on another server. The business logic behind this service is in a dll (in the GAC). It works just fine in all environment BUT ONE ! We do get this magical "warning" with no stack trace at all. We just get the name of the method called, but nothing more.

The service configuration is OK since we can browse it and we reach it with our apps (we see it in the logs). So it seems that it happens when CLR try to load the DLL.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this kind of problem?

Comment: You might try running peverify on your assemblies and seeing if that finds any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was Dynatrace bug. This product installed on the server catch all Exceptions first to do its tracing. But it seems to have a little problem throwing some back.